# Retain value of radio button after validation php

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

My issue is once user click submit the form should check for all questions that the radio button is checked.
        It should show the err message on the questions where the user didn't answer.
        But right now the form refreshed everytime after the err message is shown and the 
    previous checked radio button is lost.I also have javascript timer going on,but 
since the page get refreshed ,the timer starts all over again.
                Im newbie to php,kindly guide me through this issue.Any help is appreciated.

```
                       <?php session_start()?>
                        <?php
                        $errorexist=false;
                        if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
                                    for ($y=0;$y<5;$y++)
                                    {
                                        if(empty($_POST["question".$y])){
                                            $errorexist=true;
                                            ${"err".$y}="* Please answer question ".($y+1)."<br>";
                                        }               
                                    }
                            if (errorexist==false){
                                    header ("Location: result.php");
                                    exit;}
                        } ?>

     html part of the code
                          <li>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $err0?></span>
                    <h3>What is the smallest prime number?</h3>
                    <input type="radio" name="question0" value="A"<?php echo ($question0=='A')? 'checked':''; ?> />2<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="question0" value="B"<?php echo ($question0=='B')? 'checked':''; ?> />1<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="question0" value="C"<?php echo ($question0=='C')? 'checked':''; ?> />3<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="question0" value="D"<?php echo ($question0=='D')? 'checked':''; ?> />4<br>
                  </li>
```

Comment: I think, it would be much easier if you disable the submit button before all of the questions checked/answered.

Comment: Regarding radios: Something is missing (or wrong): Where is $question0 defined? Regarding timer: You realize the difference between what you have on server and what you have on client (that is what most ppl. get wrong at the beginning). One solution for timer would be to set a variable in session with the time the page was loaded first time (if is not define, define it, if it is leave it like that). Then you send that to client and time passed is time between current moment and the one in session (since current is measured on client you may get into some timezone issues).

Answer (score 0):

Put a condition, where if any radio button misses it displays the
error message and no need to refresh the page. Inside the PHP code,

> 1. Request submit button
> 2. Request all the radio button. i.e `$question1 = $_REQUEST['question1'];`
> 3. check if all the values are set and not empty `if(isset($question1) && !empty($question1) && $question1 !== '')`
>      do this for all, close this condition with the error message.

This might help.